# Write into /sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe with C++ application

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, usb

I am trying to make C/C++ application which should block some USB devices.

I have similar problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60725279/writing-to-a-application-octet-stream-file-on-linux), but now I need to implement that solution into C++. I just need to write some string into `/sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe`. I tried something like:

```
ofstream fDriversProbe;
fDriversProbe.open("/sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);

if(!fDriversProbe)
{
   cout << "Could not open file drivers_probe.";
}

fDriversProbe.write("1-1:1.1", strlen("1-1:1.1"));

if(!fDriversProbe.good())
{
   cout << "Could not write data to file\n";
}
```

which do not bring any errors or warnings but also do not seems to be working.

Then I decided to execute working command from code.

```
system("sudo sh -c \"echo 1-1:1.1 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe\"");
```

or

```
system("echo 1-1:1.1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe");
```

with no luck. When I do the same command (with same interface) manually from terminal, everything is working fine and USB device start to work.

Comment: No luck means "Could not open file drivers_probe", "Could not write data to file", or everything fine but device doesn't work as expected (and what exactly is expected)? I see some success story with POSIX open [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525812/read-write-into-a-device-in-c)

Comment: Everything seems to be fine, interface is written on output (same behavior as when using that command in terminal) and no error or warning. USB device is not working at all, because that command executed from C++ did not triggered driver binding for not known reasons. Thank you, I will try that solution with POSIX open() soon and will let you know.

Comment: Have you tried to write the file using `echo` command from a shell **without** C++ program? If this works, then problem could be in your C++ program, but if even plain `echo` doesn't work, then the problem is *somewhere else*.

Comment: @pptaszni I have tried to use open() and write(), but still nothing. File seems to be successfully opened and program successfully writes 7 bytes (correct length of interface) to that file. Driver binding still not triggered. I do not understand what is different in my code and this command `echo "1-1:1.1" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe`, which is working.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, as I mentioned (last sentence of my post), these 2 commands are 100% working. Triggering driver binding is last step of my application, so if I run one of these commands manually from shell after my application has finished, everything seems to be fine and working. It's pretty weird and I can't understand why at least this solution isn't working in C++ code. I am running my C++ application with sudo, so I guess that shouldn't be problem with privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flushing the ofstream object i.e fDriversProbe.flush() after every write. I had similar issue where I was trying to feed camera shutter and gain parameters using sysfs attribute exported by the driver, but the settings were not reaching driver. Accompanying the write into sysfs file with a subsequent flush fixed the issue for me.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. I have tried that, also re-opening that file every time I try to write something, but nothing changed. Only solution I have found is to use popen. So tomethink like `popen("sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe > /dev/null", "w")` and then use `write()` to write to that stream. Not the solution I like but it's working so far.